# Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple method accessible by this url:

http://localhost/SeuropWebWebApi/test

If I access it directly throug the browser, I get the response...

The problem comes when I ask the method from my Angular2 application, I try to make a simple request and the response is:

**Code: 200 with empty response**

If I try to intercept the call using Visual Studio, I notice that the method is not firing...

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/****/Test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’).**

I think that the problem comes from webapi configuration, I tried to enable CORS call using this tag in webconfig:

```
<httpProtocol>      
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />        
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

and in WebApiConfig Register method:

```
Dim cors As New System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
config.EnableCors()
```

But nothing works...

Thanks to support

Comment: Did you found any soltion for this problem ?

Comment: hi man, the problem was that I had declared cors authorization twice in webconfig and in webapiconfig and they got overwritten...

Comment: I can't share the solution because it was strictly related to my project... If you have tryied to enable cors in different area, try to remove them one by one and try to enable using only these line of code: 
Dim cors As New System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
config.EnableCors()

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I solved my problem with step by step process, here is the [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294985/cross-origin-request-blocked-azure-app-service-issue)

Comment: In my case, I also had a doubling of the header.  One from nginx, one from the proxied daemon.  Removing one of them fixed it for me.