# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Azure App Service Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

Any Ajax / JQuery call to APP Service(http://xxxx.azurewebsites.net) throw bellow error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://api-xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/demo/1234567. (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’).

**Point to be Noted:**

**1.** CORS set to * in Azure Portal

**2.** REST API also **CORS** Enabled.

```
config.EnableCors();
```

**CORS setting in controller level**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

**REST API Web.Config Settings**

```
<httpProtocol>      
<customHeaders>       
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />     
 </customHeaders>   
 </httpProtocol>
```

**JQuery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $("#b1").click(function () {               
                var jsondata = $('#s1').text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api-xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/demo/1234567",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#div1").html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        //$("#div1").html(error);
                        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
                    }                
                });

                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried to use url **https**://api-xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/demo/1234567?

Comment: @TomSun: Yes, working perfect from server, Only Ajax Request cause the problem.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, if we set CORS * in Azure WebApp portal, then we no need to set in the code. If it is acceptable, you could  remove the CORS setting from the code and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes got the success as Return from `Azure` as well as from two different (Request & Response) `localhost:port`

in *REST API* **Web.Config**

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3628800"/>
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Few changes in JQuery Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $("#b1").click(function () {               
                var jsondata = $('#s1').text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api-xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/demo/1234567",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
                    contentType: 'application/json', //<--- This Line make everthing perfect
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    complete: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                     },
                     statusCode: {
                        200: function () {
                            console.log("Success...");
                        },
                        400: function () {
                            console.log("Bad Request...");
                        }
                    },              
                });

                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
            });
        });
```

**Major changes**

> contentType: 'application/json'

**Point to be noted** (In My case : bellow line also throw `CORS Error`)

> contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'